# Issue with html tags while scraping data using beautiful soup

Tags: python-2.7, html-parsing, screen-scraping, beautifulsoup, html

Common piece of code:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import csv
import urllib2
import sys
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import islice

page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.vodafone.de/privat/tarife/red-smartphone-tarife.html').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
prices = soup.findAll('div', {"class": "price"})
```

After this I am trying following codes to get data:
Code 1:

```
for price in prices:
    print unicode(price.string).encode('utf8')
```

Output1: No Output, code runs without any error and prints nothing.

Code 2:

```
for price in prices:
    textcontent3= u' '.join(price.stripped_strings)
    if textcontent3:
        print textcontent3
```

Output2: No output again, same situation as in Output1.

Code 3:

```
for price in prices:
    fonttag = price.find('div')
    if fonttag is not None:
        print unicode(fonttag.string).encode('utf8').strip()
```

Output3: No output, same as in Output1

After this I tried printing the concerned part of the html:

Code 4:

```
print prices
```

Output4:

```
</span></div>, <div class="price">
<span id="price"><br/>
</span></div>, <div class="price">
<span id="price"><br/>
</span></div>]
```

As it can be seen from the Output4, no price value is coming in the html beautiful soup is scraping for me. While on webpage this html structure looks like this:

```
<div class="price"><span id="price">49,90 €</span><br>einmalig</div>
```

Beautiful soup is not extracting the price values as mentioned in the html page, thus I am not able to scrape data for the price.
Please help me in solving this issue & pardon my ignorance as I am new to programming.

Comment: The page uses JavaScript to replace the `<span id="price">` elements with a price from a huge block of JavaScript data embedded in the page. You'll need to extract it from there.

Comment: How do I do that? Is there anything which I can learn or use instantly? I have no background in either of the Javascript and html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page uses a large JavaScript structure to load the prices. You can load just that structure:

```
scripts = soup.find_all('script')
script = next(s.text for s in scripts if s.string and 'window.rates' in s.string)
datastring = script.split('phones=')[1].split(';window.')[0]
```

This results in a large JavaScript structure, starting with:

```
{sku844082:{name:"Samsung Galaxy SII",image:"/images/m677391_300468.jpg",deliveryTime:"Vorauss. verf&#252;gbar ab Anfang Januar",sku1444291:{p:"prod954312",e:"19.90"},sku1444286:{p:"prod954312",e:"19.90"},sku1444283:{p:"prod954312",e:"39.90"},sku1444275:{p:"prod954312",e:"59.90"},sku1104261:{p:"prod954312",e:"99.90"}},sku894279:{name:"BlackBerry Torch 9810",image:"/images/m727477_300464.jpg",deliveryTime:"Lieferbar innerhalb 48 Stunden",sku1444275:{p:"prod1004495",e:"179.90"},sku1104261:{p:"prod1004495",e:"259.90"},sku1444291:{p:"prod1004495",e:"29.90"},sku1444286:{p:"prod1004495",e:"29.90"},sku1444283:{p:"prod1004495",e:"49.90"}},sku864221:{name:"BlackBerry Bold 9900",image:"/images/m707491_300465.jpg",deliveryTime:"Lieferbar innerhalb 48 Stunden",sku1444275:{p:"prod974431",e:"129.90"},sku1104261:{p:"prod974431",e:"169.90"},sku1444291:{p:"prod974431",e:"49.90"},sku1444286:{p:"prod974431",e:"49.90"},sku1444283:{p:"prod974431",e:"89.90"}}
```

Unfortunately, that's not directly loadable with the `json` module; although valid JavaScript, without quoting around the keys it is not valid JSON. You'd need to use regular expressions to clean that up further, or grab the `p:"someprice"` information directly from that string.

Luckily the structure can be fixed with a small amount of regular expression magic:

```
import re
import json

datastring = re.sub(ur'([{,])([a-z]\w*):', ur'\1"\2":', datastring)
data = json.loads(datastring)
```

This gives you a large dictionary, with SKU keys and dictionaries with nested dicts as data, including nested SKUs with `p` product codes and `e` prices:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(data['sku864221'])
{u'deliveryTime': u'Lieferbar innerhalb 48 Stunden',
 u'image': u'/images/m707491_300465.jpg',
 u'name': u'BlackBerry Bold 9900',
 u'sku1104261': {u'e': u'169.90', u'p': u'prod974431'},
 u'sku1444275': {u'e': u'129.90', u'p': u'prod974431'},
 u'sku1444283': {u'e': u'89.90', u'p': u'prod974431'},
 u'sku1444286': {u'e': u'49.90', u'p': u'prod974431'},
 u'sku1444291': {u'e': u'49.90', u'p': u'prod974431'}}
```

Comment: But, how do I grab device name and its respective prices from this large dictionary and output them in csv. I need to have 5 rows for each devices having 5 different prices.

Comment: @atams: SO is not about providing you with cut and dry solutions; I'm happy to help you with individual problems, but *at some point* you have to do some work too. Looping over a dictionary and extracting some data in a specific form is not that hard, is it? Experiment on the python interpreter prompt until you understand the structures involved better.

Comment: Yeah, rightly said. Will do that. But right now I am stuck on this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135190/issue-with-finding-parent-of-a-particular-tag-in-html-using-python Can you please go through this.