# Converting JavaScript JSON data to Python JSON

Tags: javascript, python, json

I have JavaScript JSON data:

```
var data = '{a: 10, b: 20}'
```

I want to convert it to Python JSON. How can I do?

**My situation:** 
I have script that read text from a website. website has data in javascript variables like I show in example. I extracted variable part `'{a: 10, b: 20}'`. But for the python, it is still string format. I need to convert that data into Python JSON so I can do further work.

How can I convert JavaScript JSON to Python JSON?

Comment: First of all, that's not even valid JSON. Second of all, there is no difference between "JavaScript JSON" and "Python JSON," which is the whole point of using the same format. Just use `json.loads` in Python to decode a JSON string into a useful format.

Comment: @Elisa, refer this https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html, on github https://github.com/jsonpickle/jsonpickle

Comment: If the `data` is formatted as `{a: 10, b: 20}`, then it likely represents a JavaScript Object literal/initializer. Or a similar, custom syntax. But, no JSON is involved. Despite their relationship, especially in name and shared syntax, JSON and JavaScript do still exist separately. To parse the string, you would likely need a JavaScript parser for Python.

Answer (score 1):

*Python JSON* is a bit of a misnomer as JSON (as in JavaScript Object Notation) is a subset of JavaScript and simply describes a JavaScript object. It is an exchange format that does not depend on the language you are using it with.

You can use the [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module to parse JSON in Python, and return an equivalent Python object.

Answer (score 1):

it need regex replace before can convert it json

```
import re
import json

data = '''{a: 10, b: true, c :"string", "d" : jsVariable, e:'single'}'''

# replace single with double quote
data = data.replace("'", '"')

# wrap key with double quotes
data = re.sub(r"(\w+)\s?:", r'"\1":', data)

# wrap value with double quotes
# but not for interger or boolean
data = re.sub(r":\s?(?!(\d+|true|false))(\w+)", r':"\2"', data)

data = json.loads(data)

print(data['a']) # 10
print(json.dumps(data, indent=2)) # formatted json string
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently some libraries like [RSON](https://code.google.com/p/rson/) can help you.

According to [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19745157/parse-javascript-object-declaration-which-doesnt-use-strings-for-property-names#answer-19745205)

Answer (score 0):

`var data = '{a: 10, b: 20}'` is not a valid JSON. It is valid JavaScript

If you were to do

```
var data = JSON.stringify({ a: 10, b: 20 });
```

you would find it actually becomes

```
var data = '{ "a": 10, "b": 20 }'
```

The extra `"` around the `a` and `b` variables being the part that makes this valid JSON. The confusion comes from the fact that JavaScript is more forgiving than JSON.

Don't feel bad. You will not be the only one who will fall into this trap.