# How can I parse json from a website into python?

Tags: javascript, python, json, parsing

I am trying to scrape the news headlines from [this page](https://polymetalinternational.com/en/investors-and-media/news/press-releases/). It appears that the headlines are contained in a json-object named `App` inside a pair of script tags. If you're reading this in the future, you can assume it looked something like this

```
    string = '''{"page":{"lang":"en","error":{"state":false,"type":null}},"system":{"referrer":null,"cookie":[],"params":{"get":[],"post":[]}},"components":{"search-fast-links":[{"name":"FY 2022 preliminary financial results","link":"\/en\/investors-and-media\/news\/press-releases\/08-02-2023\/","detail":""},{"name":"Re-domiciliation Q&A","link":"\/en\/investors-and-media\/shareholder-centre\/current-qa\/","detail":""}],"press-release":{"items":[{"name":"Q4 and FY 2023 production results","date":1706648400,"type":"\u041f\u0440\u0435\u0441\u0441-\u0440\u0435\u043b\u0438\u0437\u044b","link":"\/en\/investors-and-media\/news\/press-releases\/31-01-2024\/?","theme":["Production results"],"files":[[{"name":"2024_01_31_Q4_Production_results_eng","type":"pdf","size":"402.15 Kb","link":"\/upload\/ib\/1\/24-01-31\/2024_01_31_Q4_Production_results_eng.pdf"}]]},{"name":"Notice regarding a change of a major shareholder","date":1706475600,"type":"\u041f\u0440\u0435\u0441\u0441-\u0440\u0435\u043b\u0438\u0437\u044b","link":"\/en\/investors-and-media\/news\/press-releases\/29-01-2024\/?","theme":["Regulatory disclosures","Shareholder information"],"files":[[{"name":"2024_01_29_Notice regarding_a_change_of_a_major_shareholder_eng","type":"pdf","size":"279.34 Kb","link":"\/upload\/ib\/1\/24-01-29\/2024_01_29_Notice regarding_a_change_of_a_major_shareholder_eng.pdf"}]]},{"name":"Nominated brokers for the purpose of the Exchange Offer","date":1705525200,"type":"\u041f\u0440\u0435\u0441\u0441-\u0440\u0435\u043b\u0438\u0437\u044b","link":"\/en\/investors-and-media\/news\/press-releases\/18-01-2024\/?","theme":["Shareholder information"],"files":[[{"name":"2024_01_18_Nominated_brokers_eng","type":"pdf","size":"202.73 Kb","link":"\/upload\/ib\/1\/24-01-18\/2024_01_18_Nominated_brokers_eng.pdf"}]]},{"name":"Total Voting Rights as at 29 December 2023 ","date":1703797200,"type":"\u041f\u0440\u0435\u0441\u0441-\u0440\u0435\u043b\u0438\u0437\u044b","link":"\/en\/investors-and-media\/news\/press-releases\/29-12-2023\/?","theme":["Regulatory disclosures"],"files":[[{"name":"2023_12_29_TVR_eng","type":"pdf","size":"114.49 Kb","link":"\/upload\/ib\/1\/23-12-29\/2023_12_29_TVR_eng.pdf"}]]},{"name":"Receives the most prestigious corporate social responsibility award in the Republic of Kazakhstan","date":1702414800,"type":"\u041f\u0440\u0435\u0441\u0441-\u0440\u0435\u043b\u0438\u0437\u044b","link":"\/en\/investors-and-media\/news\/press-releases\/13-12-2023\/?","theme":["ESG","Other"],"files":[[{"name":"2023_12_13_Paryz_award_eng","type":"pdf","size":"200.72 Kb","link":"\/upload\/ib\/1\/23-12-12\/2023_12_13_Paryz_award_eng.pdf"}]]},{"name":"Results of GM","date":1702242000,"type":"\u041f\u0440\u0435\u0441\u0441-\u0440\u0435\u043b\u0438\u0437\u044b","link":"\/en\/investors-and-media\/news\/press-releases\/11-12-2023\/?","theme":["Shareholder information"],"files":[[{"name":"2023_12_11_GM_results_eng","type":"pdf","size":"215.86 Kb","link":"\/upload\/ib\/1\/23-12-10\/2023_12_11_GM_results_eng.pdf"}]]},{"name":"Offer to exchange certain shares currently affected by the EU asset freeze on NSD and Notice of General Meeting","date":1700686800,"type":"\u041f\u0440\u0435\u0441\u0441-\u0440\u0435\u043b\u0438\u0437\u044b","link":"\/en\/investors-and-media\/news\/press-releases\/23-11-2023\/?","theme":["Shareholder information"],"files":[[{"name":"2023_11_23_Exchange_offer_GM_eng","type":"pdf","size":"241.23 Kb","link":"\/upload\/ib\/1\/23-11-23\/2023_11_23_Exchange_offer_GM_eng.pdf"}]]},{"name":"Q3 2023 production results","date":1698699600,"type":"\u041f\u0440\u0435\u0441\u0441-\u0440\u0435\u043b\u0438\u0437\u044b","link":"\/en\/investors-and-media\/news\/press-releases\/31-10-2023\/?","theme":["Production results"],"files":[[{"name":"2023_10_31_Q3_Production_results_eng","type":"pdf","size":"404.46 Kb","link":"\/upload\/ib\/1\/23-10-31\/2023_10_31_Q3_Production_results_eng.pdf"}]]},{"name":"Results of new share issues ","date":1696971600,"type":"\u041f\u0440\u0435\u0441\u0441-\u0440\u0435\u043b\u0438\u0437\u044b","link":"\/en\/investors-and-media\/news\/press-releases\/11-10-2023-c\/?","theme":["Other","Regulatory disclosures","Shareholder information"],"files":[[{"name":"2023_10_11_Results_of_new_share_issues_eng","type":"pdf","size":"124.73 Kb","link":"\/upload\/ib\/1\/23-10-11\/2023_10_11_Results_of_new_share_issues_eng.pdf"}]]},{"name":"Completion of Exchange Offer","date":1696971600,"type":"\u041f\u0440\u0435\u0441\u0441-\u0440\u0435\u043b\u0438\u0437\u044b","link":"\/en\/investors-and-media\/news\/press-releases\/11-10-2023-b\/?","theme":["Other","Shareholder information"],"files":[[{"name":"2023_10_11_Results_of_Exchange_Offer_eng","type":"pdf","size":"215.34 Kb","link":"\/upload\/ib\/1\/23-10-11\/2023_10_11_Results_of_Exchange_Offer_eng.pdf"}]]},{"name":"Director\/PDMR Shareholding","date":1696971600,"type":"\u041f\u0440\u0435\u0441\u0441-\u0440\u0435\u043b\u0438\u0437\u044b","link":"\/en\/investors-and-media\/news\/press-releases\/11-10-2023-a\/?","theme":["Regulatory disclosures"],"files":[[{"name":"2023_10_11_PDMR_Notification_eng","type":"pdf","size":"131.9 Kb","link":"\/upload\/ib\/1\/23-10-11\/2023_10_11_PDMR_Notification_eng.pdf"}]]},{"name":"Half-year report for the six month ended 30 June 2023","date":1695589200,"type":"\u041f\u0440\u0435\u0441\u0441-\u0440\u0435\u043b\u0438\u0437\u044b","link":"\/en\/investors-and-media\/news\/press-releases\/25-09-2023\/?","theme":["Financial results"],"files":[[{"name":"2023_09_25_POLY_1H_2023_Half_yearly_report_eng","type":"pdf","size":"2.07 Mb","link":"\/upload\/ib\/1\/23-09-25\/2023_09_25_POLY_1H_2023_Half_yearly_report_eng.pdf"}]]},{"name":"London De-listing ","date":1693281960,"type":"\u041f\u0440\u0435\u0441\u0441-\u0440\u0435\u043b\u0438\u0437\u044b","link":"\/en\/investors-and-media\/news\/press-releases\/29-08-2023\/?","theme":["Shareholder information"],"files":[[{"name":"2023_08_29_London_De-listing_eng","type":"pdf","size":"121.65 Kb","link":"\/upload\/ib\/1\/23-08-29\/2023_08_29_London_De-listing_eng.pdf"}]]},{"name":"Resumption of trading on AIX","date":1691647200,"type":"\u041f\u0440\u0435\u0441\u0441-\u0440\u0435\u043b\u0438\u0437\u044b","link":"\/en\/investors-and-media\/news\/press-releases\/10-08-2023\/?","theme":["Shareholder information"],"files":[[{"name":"2023_08_10_AIX_trading_resumption_eng","type":"pdf","size":"219.65 Kb","link":"\/upload\/ib\/1\/23-08-10\/2023_08_10_AIX_trading_resumption_eng.pdf"}]]},{"name":"Q2 2023 production results","date":1691528400,"type":"\u041f\u0440\u0435\u0441\u0441-\u0440\u0435\u043b\u0438\u0437\u044b","link":"\/en\/investors-and-media\/news\/press-releases\/09-08-2023\/?","theme":["Production results"],"files":[[{"name":"2023_08_09_Q2_Production_eng","type":"pdf","size":"405.7 Kb","link":"\/upload\/ib\/1\/23-08-09\/2023_08_09_Q2_Production_eng.pdf"}]]},{"name":"Re-Domiciliation to AIFC Completed","date":1691442000,"type":"\u041f\u0440\u0435\u0441\u0441-\u0440\u0435\u043b\u0438\u0437\u044b","link":"\/en\/investors-and-media\/news\/press-releases\/08-08-2023\/?","theme":["Shareholder information"],"files":[[{"name":"2023_08_08_Re-domiciliation_eng","type":"pdf","size":"199.45 Kb","link":"\/upload\/ib\/1\/23-08-08\/2023_08_08_Re-domiciliation_eng.pdf"}]]},{"name":"Suspension of Trading on the London Stock Exchange","date":1690862400,"type":"\u041f\u0440\u0435\u0441\u0441-\u0440\u0435\u043b\u0438\u0437\u044b","link":"\/en\/investors-and-media\/news\/press-releases\/01-08-2023\/?","theme":["Other","Shareholder information"],"files":[[{"name":"2023_08_01_London_Suspension_eng","type":"pdf","size":"221.29 Kb","link":"\/upload\/ib\/1\/23-08-02\/2023_08_01_London_Suspension_eng.pdf"}]]},{"name":"Results of GM","date":1690516800,"type":"\u041f\u0440\u0435\u0441\u0441-\u0440\u0435\u043b\u0438\u0437\u044b","link":"\/en\/investors-and-media\/news\/press-releases\/28-07-2023\/?","theme":["Shareholder information"],"files":[[{"name":"2023_07_28_GM_results_eng","type":"pdf","size":"214.79 Kb","link":"\/upload\/ib\/1\/23-07-28\/2023_07_28_GM_results_eng.pdf"}]]},{"name":"Results of AGM","date":1690257600,"type":"\u041f\u0440\u0435\u0441\u0441-\u0440\u0435\u043b\u0438\u0437\u044b","link":"\/en\/investors-and-media\/news\/press-releases\/25-07-2023\/?","theme":["Shareholder information"],"files":[[{"name":"2023_07_25_AGM_results_eng","type":"pdf","size":"244.42 Kb","link":"\/upload\/ib\/1\/23-07-25\/2023_07_25_AGM_results_eng.pdf"}]]},{"name":"Update to the timetable of the Re-domiciliation ","date":1689912000,"type":"\u041f\u0440\u0435\u0441\u0441-\u0440\u0435\u043b\u0438\u0437\u044b","link":"\/en\/investors-and-media\/news\/press-releases\/21-07-2023\/?","theme":["Shareholder information"],"files":[[{"name":"2023_07_21_Update_to_Re-domiciliaton_Timetable_eng","type":"pdf","size":"234.32 Kb","link":"\/upload\/ib\/1\/23-07-21\/2023_07_21_Update_to_Re-domiciliaton_Timetable_eng.pdf"}]]}],"nav":{"count":883,"total":45,"current":1},"filters":{"theme":[{"text":"Assets","id":540,"disabled":false,"selected":false},{"text":"Corporate governance","id":532,"disabled":false,"selected":false},{"text":"Dividends","id":531,"disabled":false,"selected":false},{"text":"ESG","id":539,"disabled":false,"selected":false},{"text":"Exploration","id":533,"disabled":false,"selected":false},{"text":"Financial results","id":530,"disabled":false,"selected":false},{"text":"Indexes and ratings","id":537,"disabled":false,"selected":false},{"text":"JV","id":534,"disabled":false,"selected":false},{"text":"Other","id":541,"disabled":false,"selected":false},{"text":"Production results","id":529,"disabled":false,"selected":false},{"text":"Regulatory disclosures","id":536,"disabled":false,"selected":false},{"text":"Reports","id":535,"disabled":false,"selected":false},{"text":"Shareholder information","id":538,"disabled":false,"selected":false}],"years":[{"text":"2024","id":2024,"disabled":false,"selected":false},{"text":"2023","id":2023,"disabled":false,"selected":false},{"text":"2022","id":2022,"disabled":false,"selected":false},{"text":"2021","id":2021,"disabled":false,"selected":false},{"text":"2020","id":2020,"disabled":false,"selected":false},{"text":"2019","id":2019,"disabled":false,"selected":false},{"text":"2018","id":2018,"disabled":false,"selected":false},{"text":"2017","id":2017,"disabled":false,"selected":false},{"text":"2016","id":2016,"disabled":false,"selected":false},{"text":"2015","id":2015,"disabled":false,"selected":false},{"text":"2014","id":2014,"disabled":false,"selected":false},{"text":"2013","id":2013,"disabled":false,"selected":false},{"text":"2012","id":2012,"disabled":false,"selected":false},{"text":"2011","id":2011,"disabled":false,"selected":false},{"text":"2010","id":2010,"disabled":false,"selected":false},{"text":"2009","id":2009,"disabled":false,"selected":false},{"text":"2008","id":2008,"disabled":false,"selected":false},{"text":"2007","id":2007,"disabled":false,"selected":false}]}},"footer":{"documents":[{"link":"\/upload\/ib\/88\/23-06-07\/Polymetal_General_Privacy_Notice_eng.pdf","name":"Privacy notice","fileInfo":"PDF (156.13 Kb)"},{"link":"\/upload\/ib\/62\/23-06-29\/2022_Polymetal_Modern_Slavery_Statement.pdf","name":"Modern Slavery Act Transparency Statement 2022","fileInfo":"PDF (435.06 Kb)"}],"links":[{"name":"Glossary ","link":"\/en\/glossary\/"},{"name":"Sitemap","link":"\/en\/sitemap\/"}],"tune":[{"name":"Contacts","link":"\/en\/contacts\/"},{"name":"Hotline","link":"\/en\/contacts\/hotline\/"}],"danger":"<div class=\"footer__info--text\">\r\n    <span>Please note that <a href=\"https:\/\/www.polymetalinternational.com\/\" class=\"link link--inline\">https:\/\/www.polymetalinternational.com\/<\/a> is the only official URL of&nbsp;Polymetal International plc.  <a href=\"https:\/\/www.polymetal.ru\/\" class=\"link link--inline\">https:\/\/www.polymetal.ru\/<\/a> is related to JSC Polymetal.<\/span>\r\n<\/div>\r\n<div class=\"footer__info--text\">\r\n    <span>Other websites even if&nbsp;they resemble the official ones and\/or contain full or&nbsp;a&nbsp;part of&nbsp;the Company&rsquo;s name in&nbsp;their URL do&nbsp;not relate to&nbsp;Polymetal International plc or&nbsp;its subsidiaries.<\/span>\r\n<\/div>\r\n<div class=\"footer__info--text\">\r\n    <span>Polymetal International plc does not have any official accounts in social media except of <a href=\"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/channel\/UCddB8YqIjZnak6mlmTcpr3w\" class=\"link link--inline\">Youtube<\/a> and <a href=\"https:\/\/www.linkedin.com\/company\/polymetal\" class=\"link link--inline\">LinkedIn<\/a>. Any statements purportedly provided on behalf of a company is deliberate misrepresentation.<\/span>\r\n<\/div>"}}}
    '''
    import json
    json.loads(string)
```

My question is the following: What's the best way to parse this to python something that python will recognize as json?

1. I had a look at: "js2py", but I couldn't find anything that did what I want.
2. I also tried to use string.replace. After replacing all booleans and nonetype with the python equivalents to javascript, I was able to put it through json.load, but I'm concerned with simply replacing every substring of 'false' with 'False', and 'null' with 'None' because the data might change in the future such that either 'false' or 'null' appears in the middle of some other substring that is not a bool, and by replacing it, the contents can get changed in unpredictable ways.
3. I also had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25458974/converting-javascript-json-data-to-python-json), which at first glance looks like the same question, but the answer that was provided was specific to the json data that the OP provided. It would be positive to have an answer independent of the actual content which would work for all json.
4. I tried to remove `App =` and `;`, and put the json into the variable called `string` and put it through json.loads. But I'm getting lots of errors:

> ```
> >>> json.loads(string)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
>     return _default_decoder.decode(s)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
>     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
>     obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 2 column 10378 (char 10378)
> ```

Comment: drop the `App =` at start and `;` part at the end, and just parse it in python as json string with what ever package/lib/method you want.

Comment: There is no such thing as *Python JSON* and *Javascript JSON*. There is only one JSON. That's the whole point of JSON, so it can be used to interchange information between different systems which might use different programming languages. What you need to do is serialize Json in one system and deserialize it (~ transform it into an programming language specific representation of the JSON data) in the other. All modern languages provide bulit-in support for (de-)serialization of JSON or if they don't there is a library.

Comment: @Marc I tried that. I will update my question

Comment: Note that JSON is a subset of JavaScript syntax. For example, JavaScript allows you to use either single or double quotes, JSON only allows double quotes. The quotes are optional in JS for object keys if they're valid identifiers, not optional in JSON. So you can't generally count on being able to parse a JS literal as JSON.

Comment: Your error message mentions column 10378 of line 2. None of the lines in your example are that long. So we can't tell what's wrong.

Comment: I went to the URL you mentioned. I removed `App =` and `;`, pasted it into jsonlint.com, and it said it was fine.

Comment: @MikkeMus Next time please include what you have already tried and the error message. If not this makes harder to help you and increase unnecessary the comments chains! Also: Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Barmar I also get it to work in jsonlint, but not in python.

Comment: @Marc I've done it now.

Comment: @Mushroomator I've removed the references to the platforms because I have the impression that it was problematic. Now you will find the defining characteristics of the question sprinkled throughout.

Comment: I copied and pasted into a python script and I got the same error. I'm not sure why, I can't see anything wrong around that column.

Comment: I'm not sure what's different, but the code in Feijoes's answer works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if you are using selenium or BeautifulSoup but
Try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

url = 'https://polymetalinternational.com/en/investors-and-media/news/press-releases/'
response = requests.get(url)

if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    # Find the script tag containing the 'App' object
    def filter_scripts(text):
     
        if text:
            return "App = " in text
        return False
    script_tag = soup.find('script', text=filter_scripts)

    # Extract the content of the 'App' object
    app_content = script_tag.text.split('App = ')[1].strip()[:-1]

    # Load the content as JSON
    app_data = json.loads(app_content.split("};")[0] + "}" )

    headlines = app_data['components']['press-release']['items']

    for headline in headlines:
        print(f"Name: {headline['name']}")
        print(f"Date: {headline['date']}")
        print(f"Link: {headline['link']}")
        print()
```

Comment: FYI, `text=` is deprecated, it should be `string=`. And you could just use `string=re.compile('App =')`

Comment: It worked after I changed the line to `app_content = script_tag.renderContents().decode("utf-8").split('App = ')[1].strip()[:-1]`