# How can I parse Javascript variables using python?

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The problem: A website I am trying to gather data from uses Javascript to produce a graph. I'd like to be able to pull the data that is being used in the graph, but I am not sure where to start. For example, the data might be as follows:

```
var line1=
[["Wed, 12 Jun 2013 01:00:00 +0000",22.4916114807,"2 sold"],
["Fri, 14 Jun 2013 01:00:00 +0000",27.4950008392,"2 sold"],
["Sun, 16 Jun 2013 01:00:00 +0000",19.5499992371,"1 sold"],
["Tue, 18 Jun 2013 01:00:00 +0000",17.25,"1 sold"],
["Sun, 23 Jun 2013 01:00:00 +0000",15.5420341492,"2 sold"],
["Thu, 27 Jun 2013 01:00:00 +0000",8.79045295715,"3 sold"],
["Fri, 28 Jun 2013 01:00:00 +0000",10,"1 sold"]];
```

This is pricing data (Date, Price, Volume). I've found another question here - [Parsing variable data out of a js tag using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298201/parsing-variable-data-out-of-a-javascript-tag-using-python) - which suggests that I use JSON and BeautifulSoup, but I am unsure how to apply it to this particular problem because the formatting is slightly different. In fact, in this problem the code looks more like python than any type of JSON dictionary format.

I suppose I could read it in as a string, and then use XPATH and some funky string editing to convert it, but this seems like too much work for something that is already formatted as a Javascript variable.

So, what can I do here to pull this type of organized data from this variable while using python? (I am most familiar with python and BS4)

Comment: except the line break after `=` and the `var` keyword, the rest is valid in python

Comment: Is that the actual code? or is it a variable called `line1` which is a list of lists? If it's the latter, you could `for list in line1: do_something_with(list[0], list[1], list2])`

Comment: It's a variable called line1, which is part of the page contents on load, and is a list of lists.

Comment: So basically it's a string of a javascript variable? Not an actual python variable. I am afraid you will have to use some kind of parsing module or strip the string of all unnecessary text and `exec()` it. After using `exec()` you can do all kinds of things with it.

Comment: There is no way I can just tell some parser to grab the contents of line1? This seems like it should be so simple...

Comment: Sure, it doesn't look like a JSON dictionary format—but everything between the `var line1=` and the `;` is a perfectly-good JSON array format… If you're trying to parse arbitrary JS code, of course, you can't count on that always being true… but then you also can't count on anything; there could just as easily be arbitrary JS expressions as there could be JS array literals that aren't valid as JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so there are a few ways to do it, but I ended up simply using a regular expression to find everything between `line1=` and `;`

```py
#Read page data as a string
pageData = sock.read()
#set p as regular expression
p = re.compile('(?<=line1=)(.*)(?=;)')
#find all instances of regular expression in pageData
parsed = p.findall(pageData)
#evaluate list as python code => turn into list in python
newParsed = eval(parsed[0])
```

Regex is nice when you have good coding, but is this method better (EDIT: or worse!) than any of the other answers here?

EDIT: I ultimately used the following:

```py
#Read page data as a string
pageData = sock.read()
#set p as regular expression
p = re.compile('(?<=line1=)(.*)(?=;)')
#find all instances of regular expression in pageData
parsed = p.findall(pageData)
#load as JSON instead of using evaluate to prevent risky execution of unknown code
newParsed = json.loads(parsed[0])
```

Comment: `eval` is bad for many reasons; it's almost always better to use something more restrictive like `json.loads` or `ast.literal_eval`. Sure, there could be perfectly safe and valid-as-Python code that happens to work even though it isn't a literal (like 'abc' + 'def'), but you're at least as likely to run into an expression that means something different as Python—or even does something unsafe. (Imagine what happens if someone gives you `var line1=__import__('os').system('rm -rf ~/')`…)

Answer (score 11):

If your format really is just one or more `var foo = [JSON array or object literal];`, you can just write a dotall regex to extract them, then parse each one as JSON. For example:

```
>>> j = '''var line1=
[["Wed, 12 Jun 2013 01:00:00 +0000",22.4916114807,"2 sold"],
["Fri, 14 Jun 2013 01:00:00 +0000",27.4950008392,"2 sold"],
["Sun, 16 Jun 2013 01:00:00 +0000",19.5499992371,"1 sold"],
["Tue, 18 Jun 2013 01:00:00 +0000",17.25,"1 sold"],
["Sun, 23 Jun 2013 01:00:00 +0000",15.5420341492,"2 sold"],
["Thu, 27 Jun 2013 01:00:00 +0000",8.79045295715,"3 sold"],
["Fri, 28 Jun 2013 01:00:00 +0000",10,"1 sold"]];\s*$'''
>>> values = re.findall(r'var.*?=\s*(.*?);', j, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
>>> for value in values:
...     print(json.loads(value))
[[['Wed, 12 Jun 2013 01:00:00 +0000', 22.4916114807, '2 sold'],
  ['Fri, 14 Jun 2013 01:00:00 +0000', 27.4950008392, '2 sold'],
  ['Sun, 16 Jun 2013 01:00:00 +0000', 19.5499992371, '1 sold'],
  ['Tue, 18 Jun 2013 01:00:00 +0000', 17.25, '1 sold'],
  ['Sun, 23 Jun 2013 01:00:00 +0000', 15.5420341492, '2 sold'],
  ['Thu, 27 Jun 2013 01:00:00 +0000', 8.79045295715, '3 sold'],
  ['Fri, 28 Jun 2013 01:00:00 +0000', 10, '1 sold']]]
```

Of course this makes a few assumptions:

- A semicolon at the end of the line must be an actual statement separator, not the middle of a string. This should be safe because JS doesn't have Python-style multiline strings.
- The code actually does have semicolons at the end of each statement, even though they're optional in JS. Most JS code has those semicolons, but it obviously isn't guaranteed.
- The array and object literals really are JSON-compatible. This definitely isn't guaranteed; for example, JS can use single-quoted strings, but JSON can't. But it does work for your example.
- Your format really is this well-defined. For example, if there might be a statement like `var line2 = [[1]] + line1;` in the middle of your code, it's going to cause problems.

Note that if the data might contain JavaScript literals that aren't all valid JSON, but are all valid Python literals (which isn't likely, but isn't impossible, either), you can use `ast.literal_eval` on them instead of `json.loads`. But I wouldn't do that unless you know this is the case.

Comment: Right. I think the pages I am scraping are pretty well formatted, but having an extra line1= somewhere would really screw things up.

Comment: You mean having a stray `line1=` somewhere, or you mean having `line1=` without the `var` before it? The former would just fail to match and be skipped, which is fine. The latter would also fail to match and be skipped, but might _not_ be fine. If that's an issue, you need a different regex. Really, regex isn't appropriate unless you can clearly define your input format; if you're just guessing at the format, you probably want something looser and more verbose, maybe a real parser built in `pyparsing`.

Comment: It seems like this project is pretty clearly defined, which is why regex worked. However, I obviously don't know about all of the other pages that I intend to scrape. I'll probably just have to use regex until something breaks and go from there.

Comment: As long as it's appropriate to run on a bunch of pages, then debug the regex on the first one that fails, and repeat ad nauseum, that's reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

The following makes a few assumptions such as knowing how the page is formatted, but a way of getting your example into memory on *Python* is like this

```py
# example data
data = 'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar\r\nfoo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar \r\nvar line1=\r\n[["Wed, 12 Jun 2013 01:00:00 +0000",22.4916114807,"2 sold"],\r\n["Fri, 14 Jun 2013 01:00:00 +0000",27.4950008392,"2 sold"],\r\n["Sun, 16 Jun 2013 01:00:00 +0000",19.5499992371,"1 sold"],\r\n["Tue, 18 Jun 2013 01:00:00 +0000",17.25,"1 sold"],\r\n["Sun, 23 Jun 2013 01:00:00 +0000",15.5420341492,"2 sold"],\r\n["Thu, 27 Jun 2013 01:00:00 +0000",8.79045295715,"3 sold"],\r\n["Fri, 28 Jun 2013 01:00:00 +0000",10,"1 sold"]];\r\nfoo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar\r\nfoo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar'
# find your variable's start and end
x = data.find('line1=') + 6
y = data.find(';', x)
# so you can get just the relevant bit
interesting = data[x:y].strip()
# most dangerous step! don't do this on unknown sources
parsed = eval(interesting)
# maybe you'd want to use JSON instead, if the data has the right syntax
from json import loads as JSON
parsed = JSON(interesting)
# now parsed is your data
```

Comment: I would definitely not use `eval` here. If you want to handle anything that's a valid Python literal, use `ast.literal_eval`. But you probaly don't even want that.

Comment: You basically had the same thing I had in mind, but I just used a regex instead. Although I did end up using eval...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a python variable with a javascript line/block as a string like`"var line1 = [[a,b,c], [d,e,f]];"`, you could use the following few lines of code.

```
>>> code = """var line1 = [['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f'], ['g','h','i']];"""
>>> python_readable_code = code.strip("var ;")
>>> exec(python_readable_code)
>>> print(line1)
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

`exec()` Will run the code that is formatted as a string. In this case it will set the variable `line1` to a list with lists.

And than you could use something like this:

```
for list in line1:
    print(list[0], list[1], list[2])
    # Or do something else with those values, like save them to a file
```

Comment: You don't really need to strip the semicolons; they're valid statement separators in Python, even if they're only separating a statement from nothing. But more importantly, `strip("var ;")` is going to be dangerous if the variable names could be, say, `a_line`…

Comment: And even more importantly, trying to transformed the JS to Python and execute it is really, really hacky and unsafe. It will work safely in the exact same cases that just splitting and calling `ast.literal_eval` on the right side would, but that would be a lot safer, and would allow you to store the variables wherever you want (e.g., in a dict) instead of forcing them into locals (which is almost never what you want).