# Scraping messy source page with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to do some web scraping using Python and Beautiful Soup, but the source page of the webpage is not the prettiest. The code below is a minor part of the source page:

```
...717301758],"birthdayFriends":2,"lastActiveTimes":{"719317510":0,"719435783":0,...
```

I want to get the parameter '2' after the string 'birthdayFriends', but I have no idea how to get it. So far i have written the code below, but it only prints a empty list.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Create an OpenerDirector with support for Basic HTTP Authentication...
auth_handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
auth_handler.add_password(realm='PDQ Application',
                          uri='myWebpage',
                          user='myUsername',
                          passwd='myPassword')
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_handler)
# ...and install it globally so it can be used with urlopen.
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
page = urllib2.urlopen('myWebpage')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

bf = soup.findAll('birthdayFriends')

print bf

>> []
```

Comment: BeautifulSoup is an html parser, the fragment you've shown doesn't look like an html at all. Is it inside a "script" tag?

Comment: Yes, it is inside a script tag. Is there any thing to do about it then? maybe another library than Beautiful Soup?

Comment: Well, one way to get the data from the script tag is to use regular expressions: e.g. locate the script element with BS, then parse the contents of the script tag with regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

suppose somewhere in the html there is a script tag like the following:

```
<script>
var x = {"birthdayFriends":2,"lastActiveTimes":{"719317510":0,"719435783":0}}
</script>
```

then your code might look something like:

```
script = soup.findAll('script')[0] # or the number it appears in the file
# take the json part
j = bf.text.split('=')[1]

import json
# load json string to a dictionary
d = json.loads(j, strict=False)
print d["birthdayFriends"]
```

in case the content of the script tag is more complicated, consider loop over the script lines or see [How can I parse Javascript variables using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368058/how-can-i-parse-javascript-variables-using-python)

also, for parsing JavaScript in python also see [pynoceros](https://code.google.com/p/pynoceros/)