# parsing JavaScript code in HTML source

Tags: python

How do I parse JavaScript code within HTML source with Python, for example I want to extract the productList object

here is my source below;

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="content-wrapper" class="row-fluid clearfix" role="contentinfo">
<!-- html content -->
</div>


   <script>
    var productList = { "daaa" : "ddddd"};
   </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do either of these help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390992/javascript-parser-in-python  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368058/how-can-i-parse-javascript-variables-using-python

Comment: one issue you may encounter at some point is that `var productList = { daaa : function() {}};` is valid JS, but not valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at the BeautifulSoup - it can help you extract JavaScript code from an HTML file (but not parse/run it):

```
source = """<html>...</html>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(source)
js_code = soup.find_all("script")[0].text
```

Then you can use some JavaScript interpreter to run the code and get the variables - there are some out there like [this one](https://code.google.com/p/pynarcissus/) or [this one](https://github.com/mstepniowski/jspy). Just Google it.

Comment: what do you think of using regexp instead to parse the extracted JavaScript?

Comment: @Parker, I am not sure if that's a good idea, never tried to parse any proramming language with regex myself thought. I guess you could try. Btw, you could try to use [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/): it allows you to create your own parsers to parse different languages

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to add the fuction so the computer can read if it is javascript and python, 
use this:

```
script type="text/javascript">  <!-------or python----></script>
```

Comment: Hello Ben Riley, Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a complete answer; please go back and edit to fully answer the question.