# Web scrape for apis

Tags: python, api

To find the APIs a website is using is pretty simple, Just open developer tools in chrome.  However, what if I wanted to get the APIs from a list of websites?  Can I do the same task programmatically?

---

added some detail following 'Bench Vue' comment below.

As an example google.com makes the following calls.  How can I get the list below from the google.com url using python?

[image]

Comment: Can you point out which web site for get APIs? Screen capture make easy to what are you talking about.

Comment: You need to find something in Python, or an external tool Python can use, which is capable of parsing and interpreting the HTML and JS returned by a server so you can extract the URLs the page wants to load. Also some things may not be loaded directly from the page itself, but from one of the pages it loads. You might find this question helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27114673/parsing-javascript-code-in-html-source. I suspect that it may be extremely non trivial to interpret returned JS for additional resources the page is trying to load.