# Scraping Javascript variables into Python

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the following data from http://maps.latimes.com/neighborhoods/population/density/neighborhood/list/:

```
  var hoodFeatures = {
            type: "FeatureCollection",
            features: [{
                type: "Feature",
                properties: {
                    name: "Koreatown",
                    slug: "koreatown",
                    url: "/neighborhoods/neighborhood/koreatown/",
                    has_statistics: true,
                    label: 'Rank: 1<br>Population per Sqmi: 42,611',
                    population: "115,070",
                    stratum: "high"
                },
                geometry: { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -118.286908, 34.076510 ], [ -118.289208, 34.052511 ], [ -118.315909, 34.052611 ], [ -118.323009, 34.054810 ], [ -118.319309, 34.061910 ], [ -118.314093, 34.062362 ], [ -118.313709, 34.076310 ], [ -118.286908, 34.076510 ] ] ] ] }
            },
```

From the above html, I want to take each of:

```
name
population per sqmi
population
geometry
```

and turn it into a data frame by name

So far I've tried

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response_obj = requests.get('http://maps.latimes.com/neighborhoods/population/density/neighborhood/list/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response_obj,'lxml')
```

The object has the script info, but I don't understand how to use the json module as advised in this thread:
[Parsing variable data out of a javascript tag using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298201/parsing-variable-data-out-of-a-javascript-tag-using-python)

```
json_text = '{%s}' % (soup.partition('{')[2].rpartition('}')[0],)
value = json.loads(json_text)
value
```

I get this error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-37c4c0188ed0> in <module>
      1 #Splits the text on the first bracket and last bracket of the javascript into JSON format
----> 2 json_text = '{%s}' % (soup.partition('{')[2].rpartition('}')[0],)
      3 value = json.loads(json_text)
      4 value
      5 #import pprint

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: `soup` is not string and it may tread `partition` as tag name `<partition>` which not exists and you get `None`. You would have to work with `soup.text` which is a string. You could also find tag `<script>` to work only with text wich may have javascript code - `code = soup.find('script').text`

Answer (score 0):

You can't really use `json.loads` because `hoodFeatures` object is not really a json. In a  proper json, every key is surrounded with double quotes `"`

You could try adding quotes around keys manually (using regular expressions).
Another option is using Selenium to execute that JS and get the `JSON.stringify` output of it.

## Answer using manual cleanup:

This one cleans up JS code and turns it into a JSON that can be parsed properly. However keep in mind that it is by no means robust, and may break at any sight of unexpected input.

```py
import json
import re

js = '''
 var hoodFeatures = {
            type: "FeatureCollection",
            features: [
            {
                type: "Feature",
                properties: {
                    name: "Beverlywood",
                    slug: "beverlywood",
                    url: "/neighborhoods/neighborhood/beverlywood/",
                    has_statistics: true,
                    label: 'Rank: 131<br>Population per Sqmi: 7,654',
                    population: "6,080",
                    stratum: "middle"
                },
                geometry: {  }
            }]
        }
'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unprefixed = js.split('{', maxsplit=1)[1]
    unsuffixed = unprefixed.rsplit('}', maxsplit=1)[0]
    quotes_replaced = unsuffixed.replace('\'', '"')
    rebraced = f'{{{quotes_replaced}}}'
    keys_quoted = []
    for line in rebraced.splitlines():
        line = re.sub('^\s+([^:]+):', '"\\1":', line)
        keys_quoted.append(line)
    json_raw = '\n'.join(keys_quoted)
    # print(json_raw)
    parsed = json.loads(json_raw)
    for feat in parsed['features']:
        props = feat['properties']
        name, pop = props['name'], int(props['population'].replace(',', ''))
        geo = feat['geometry']
        pop_per_sqm = re.findall('per Sqmi: ([\d,]+)', props['label'])[0].replace(',', '')
        pop_per_sqm = int(pop_per_sqm)

        print(name, pop, pop_per_sqm, geo)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure how to do that with the beautiful soup, yet another option might be to likely design an expression and extract our desired values:

```
(?:name|population per sqmi|population)\s*:\s*"?(.*?)\s*["']|(?:geometry)\s*:\s*({.*})
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZhsD7i/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"(?:name|population per sqmi|population)\s*:\s*\"?(.*?)\s*[\"']|(?:geometry)\s*:\s*({.*})"

test_str = ("var hoodFeatures = {\n"
    "            type: \"FeatureCollection\",\n"
    "            features: [{\n"
    "                type: \"Feature\",\n"
    "                properties: {\n"
    "                    name: \"Koreatown\",\n"
    "                    slug: \"koreatown\",\n"
    "                    url: \"/neighborhoods/neighborhood/koreatown/\",\n"
    "                    has_statistics: true,\n"
    "                    label: 'Rank: 1<br>Population per Sqmi: 42,611',\n"
    "                    population: \"115,070\",\n"
    "                    stratum: \"high\"\n"
    "                },\n"
    "                geometry: { \"type\": \"MultiPolygon\", \"coordinates\": [ [ [ [ -118.286908, 34.076510 ], [ -118.289208, 34.052511 ], [ -118.315909, 34.052611 ], [ -118.323009, 34.054810 ], [ -118.319309, 34.061910 ], [ -118.314093, 34.062362 ], [ -118.313709, 34.076310 ], [ -118.286908, 34.076510 ] ] ] ] }\n"
    "            },\n")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```